# Mysql ADO.Net inserts causing error when creating new tables or inserting records

Tags: mysql, ssis, ado.net, etl

When I try to create a simple data flow between flat file/OLE DB to ADO.Net Destination I get an error and it fails my package, almost right away.

> [ADO NET Destination [2]] Error: An exception has occurred during data insertion, the message returned from the provider is: ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.2(a) Driver][mysqld-5.6.27-log]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"test_etl2" ("id", "phone", "var1", "var2", "var3", "var4", "var5", "name1", "na' at line 1
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "ADO NET Destination" (2) failed with error code 0xC020844B while processing input "ADO NET Destination Input" (9). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Flat File Source returned error code 0xC02020C4.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

*Screenshot*

[image: SSIS error image]

Comment: Please post the actual statement that's generating the error.

Comment: It is a data flow task, more description added

Comment: `ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.2(a) Driver][mysqld-5.6.27-log]You have an error in your SQL syntax; ` is your error, we won't be able to help if we don't see the SQL statement